# Visual Studio 2013 Add View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

i create the class Poi and the class Address.

```
    public class Poi
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    // ...
}
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

How it is possible to generate the view Poi/Details.cshtml including all fields of the address?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to pass the `Address` down as a Model to the View.

In your Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details() 
{
   var model = new Address();
   model.Street = "Test address";

   return View(model);
}
```

Then in your View, add the following:

```
@model Address
```

Which will allow the View to know that it is dealing with a strongly typed `Address` model.

You can then use `@Html.DisplayFor` to list all of the properties within the view, for example:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Street)
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Zip)
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.City)
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Country)
```

However, it would be best to create a `ViewModel` rather than using the `Address` POCO directly. The ViewModel may get this information from a different layer, for example a Database or a Web Service, which could then invoke that layer independently rather than in the Controller, this allows for better separation of concerns.

Comment: I don't want to generate any view for the address but one for the POI including all address fields. If i generate the view for the POI model in VS2013 it leaves the address.

Comment: @mlauth - then use the POI model and access the `Address` property within that.  `@HtmlDisplayFor(m => m.Address.Street)` - `IF` the POI has more than one address you will need a collection and store them in an `IEnumerable<Address>` and then iterate over them in the View.

Comment: Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: @mlauth - look at MVC scaffolding.

Comment: I tried the MVC scaffolding. I used the “add view” option in my controller. But is there any way to automatically generate a *complete* view including *all* fields of poi and address without flatting my poi object, if not I go to use AutoMapper.